# Where is Pyvenv?

Tags: 14.04, python

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which comes with Python 3.4.3

I want to use the pyvenv command, but when I try running `pyven` I get `command not found`, and if I try `pyvenv-3.4` it tells me to use apt-get to install the `python 3.4` package. How can I get pyvenv up and running?

Comment: Are you looking for [`virtualenv`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python-virtualenv/filelist)?

Comment: No, I'm looking for `pyvenv`. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html

Comment: That would be [python3.4-venv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/python3.4-venv), then.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting command not found.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given by nasser alshammari on [Install python3-venv module on linux mint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272200/4868684). Basically doing as Danny wrote and then calling the module as above:

```
python3 -m venv test
```